# Error while attempting to add packages in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteorite

So I am very new to Meteor, and I was sifting through some example apps and open source projects when I came across this simple chat application:
(https://github.com/BenderV/simplechat)
I wanted to download the project, run it on my local server, and mess around with the code to learn more about what does what, and how to use the Meteor framework. I simply downloaded the .zip file from github and tried to run it (using the `meteor` in my terminal. However I got the following error when I ran the application locally in my browser:

```
Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log.

=> Errors prevented startup:

While building the application:
error: no such package: 'accounts-guest'
error: no such package: 'user-status'
error: no such package: 'accounts-testing'
error: no such package: 'fontawesome4'
error: no such package: 'iron-router'
error: no such package: 'bootstrap-3'
error: no such package: 'fast-render'
error: no such package: 'jquery-titlealert'
error: no such package: 'related'

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I can (obviously) infer from the nature of the log that the error that I am experiencing is because I don't have the correct packages installed (the one that are listed, obviously).

So keeping this in mind, I researched how to add packages to meteor (using instructions I found on Atmosphere JS pages of the respective packages). However, when I entered the command that was provided by Atmosphere into my terminal (for example for, 'accounts-guest' package I entered: `meteor add artwells:accounts-guest`). Unfortunately doing this did not work, and I was given something like the following error in the terminal: `artwells:accounts-guest: no such package`

I have no idea what to do, the packages will not install so I can not try this code. I come from experience with Rails, and in Rails if you needed to install "gems" (pretty much the same thing as packages in Meteor) you could just enter `bundle install` into the terminal to download and install undefined packages. Is there something like this in Meteor? I have heard of something called Meteorite, but am unsure what it is and how to use it.

Anyways I really would appreciate any help in getting me past this minor roadblock on my way to learning Meteor!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an older project which use the old packaging system 'meteorite' = 'mrt' on the command line.

I suggest you try a newer example, Meteor ships with a few.  Once you have Meteor installed you can create an example app by typing one of the following commands :

```
meteor create --example leaderboard
meteor create --example todos
meteor create --example localmarket
```

And yes, there is a very similar mechanism to the gems commands you are accustomed to.  Simply running a project 'meteor' should download its dependencies.  Also you can run 'meteor update' if you want to update to the latest versions for your project.

Last August there was a major update to the meteor package management system, you can read more about it here : https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/08/26/meteor-090-new-packaging-system

So, for any examples you'd like to check out, try and get a recent one, from meteor 1.0.   In newer versions of meteor those instructions on Atmosphere should work out fine for you.

You can see what version of meteor a project is running by looking at this file ".meteor/release"  inside a meteor project : 
https://github.com/BenderV/simplechat/blob/master/.meteor/release
so you can see that one is old.

good luck!

Comment: Thank you that really helped! Would there be a way to possibly update/convert the program to the newest version? I really like this kind of application, and I want to know how it works...thanks once again!

Comment: yes, that is definitely possible.  The amount of effort varies quite a bit though.  If there are particular aspects of an older program you are really interested in using, I think it's best to pull out source code chunks and sort of manually port it over.  Updating projects pre 0.9 to post 0.9 can be significant. There is no automated mechanism to port an old meteor project that I'm aware, there are way too many nuances involved.

Comment: you could try to run old versions of meteor too, I don't recommend doing it.   I tried running the project you mentioned in meteorite and it installed but it barked all sorts of errors on startup, so I gave up.  Most likely if the project has a significant feature, there is another up to date project you can find with the same feature.